# How big was the first transistor?

Tags: soft-question, history, semiconductor-physics, electronics

The first working point-contact transistor made in 1947 by Bell Labs. I'm looking for specific dimensions, all I've been able to find is "Fits in the palm of your hand".

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4):

From "The Transistor, A Semi-Conductor Triode", by J. Bardeen and W. H. Brattain, Phys Rev. 74(2), 230-231 (1948):

"The device consists of three electrodes placed on a block of germanium as shown schematically in Fig. 1.  Two, called the emitter and collector, are of the point-contact rectifier type and are placed in close proximity (separation ~0.005 to 0.025 cm) on the upper surface.  The third is a large area low resistance contact on the base."

So, the actual device was much smaller than your (or my) palm.  Now, the support for the device was probably bigger.  Sze's book had a picture of the device on the cover long ago - not sure about new editions.

[image]

(*Replica of the first transistor*)

Comment: I've added an image, fell free to revert.

Comment: Looks great - thanks for the picture. As usual, the packaging is bigger than the actual device...